# if $A$ and $B$ share eigenvalues, show there exists a matrix $S$ such that $AS=SB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

- Let $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with $n \geq 2$. If $A$ and $B$ share eigenvalues, demonstrate the existence of a non-zero matrix $S \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $AS = SB$.
- Now, considering $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, suppose that for every $C \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, the system $AX + XB = C$ has a solution in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Prove that either $A$ or $B$ is invertible.

**Additional Note:**
In the initial question, it may resemble matrix similarity, but because $S$ doesn't necessarily need to be invertible, the desired outcome differs from matrix similarity. I am uncertain about how to approach this problem.

I understand it's generally discouraged to pose multiple questions, but I perceived these as interconnected and solvable together. I apologize if this isn't the case, and if the community advises, I am willing to delete one of the questions.

Any assistance or guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: For your first question, try an $S$ of rank $1$, i.e. $u v^T$ for suitable vectors $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Your second is false, try $A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr}$ and $B = \pmatrix{0 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}$.  Maybe the equation was supposed to be $AX + X B = C$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I edited the second one. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $\lambda$ is a common eigenvalue for $A$ and $B$ . Then, using that the eigenvalues of $B^*$ are the conjugates of the eigenvalues of $B$,  there exist unit vectors $x,y$ such that
$$
Ax=\lambda x,\qquad\qquad B^*y=\overline\lambda y.
$$
The second equality, taking adjoints, is $y^*B=\lambda y^*$. Then
$$
Axy^*-xy^*B=\lambda xy^*-\lambda xy^*=0. 
$$

For the second part, consider the map $X\longmapsto AX+XB$. This map is linear, and the hypothesis is that it is surjective. As the domain and codomain have the same dimension, it follows that the map is injective. If both $A$ and $B$ are singular, then $0$ is a common eigenvalue, and by the first part of the question (applied to $A$ and $-B$ with the common eigenvalue $0$) there would exist nonzero $S$ such that $AS-SB=0$, contradicting the injectivity. It follows that at least one of $A,B$ is non-singular.